# Can anyone help me figure out why I cannot access my cfc with an ajax request, but have no problem via browser?

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, cfc, application.cfc

I am working on a simple form using ColdFusion MX7. I have a pair of text inputs I want to populate based on a what is selected in a cfselect. Any Ajax calls to my CFC return a 404 error. If I access the CFC from my browser I get no such error. I made this using Ben Nadel's example of making a custom java proxy for a cfc. The cfc is located in the same folder as the cfm page that this script is on. Here is the pertinent code:

```
 function RemoteCFC(){
        this.name = " ";
        return( this );
       }


      // This handles the remote calls to the CFCs.
      RemoteCFC.prototype.MakeRemoteCall = function(strMethod, objData, fnSuccess, fnError){

      // Create a data struct and extend it with the method
      // name and the data to be passed.
      var objRemoteData = {};

      // Extend the remote data set.
      $.extend(objRemoteData, objData, {method: strMethod, returnFormat: "json"});
      // Make the AJAX call to the remote method.
      $.ajax({type: "get", url: (this.Name + ".cfc"), data: objRemoteData, dataType: "json", 
             success: fnSuccess, error: fnError});

      // Return this for method chaining.
      return( this );
   }

   // Create a new core remote object. We will need this
   // to create the prototype chain such that the other
   // proxy classes can extend this.
   objRemoteCFC = new RemoteCFC();
   // Create a Javascript proxy for this given CFC.
   function RecallService(){
      this.Name = "RecallCountFunctions";
   }

   // Extend the core CFC Proxy functionality.
   RecallService.prototype = objRemoteCFC;


    RecallService.prototype.getInspected = function( objData, fnSuccess, fnError ){
        this.MakeRemoteCall( "getInspected", objData, fnSuccess, fnError );
    }

    //Define another remote method wrapper. 
    RecallService.prototype.getHeld = function( objData, fnSuccess, fnError ){
        this.MakeRemoteCall( "getHeld", objData, fnSuccess, fnError );
    }

   $(   
      function(){
        var myRecallService = new RecallService();

        $( "select[ name = 'CountChosen' ]" ).change( function(){
           var selectedCount = $( "select[ name = 'CountChosen' ]" );
           var inspected = $("input[name='numInspected']");
           var held = $("input[name='numHeld']");

           if (selectedCount.val() != "0"){
               EnableForm();
               myRecallService.getInspected({store: "#cgi.AUTH_USER#", id: selectedCount}, function
                      ( objResponse ){SetValue("inspected", objResoponse );}, function( objResponse ){
                      alert( objResponse.responseText );});                     
               myRecallService.getHeld({store: "#cgi.AUTH_USER#", id: selectedCount}, function
                      ( objResponse ){SetValue("held", objResponse);}, function( objResponse ){
                      alert( objResponse.responseText);});                      
           }
       });
   }
```

Sorry about the long post, I didn't want to leave out annything that may help. I am also not using Application.cfc or an onRequest method which I heard may cause issues.

If you need to see my cfc let me know I can post it as well.

Fix was:

```
Change:
   id: selectedCount
To:
   id: selectedCount.val()
```

Comment: What does Firebug tell you about the request?

Comment: I'm a bit new to all of this how do I see that with firebug?

Comment: Firebug is showing an interal server error form IIS (http: 500)

Comment: Ok, so check your error logs - what is logged in the CF errors?

Comment: Oh dude! returnformat=json doesn't work in CF7. In CF7 you can return WDDX (the default), or a plain string IF you use returnTYpe=xml.

Comment: I am getting the WDDx back now, and it was my ajax call I needed to use selectedCount.val() not just selected count.

Comment: Ok - so your last comment isn't clear. Are you good now or not?

Comment: Yeah I am good. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And besides Ray's question about what Firebug (or Charles or Fiddler or other proxies may tell you), which should certainly help if it's really just a 404 error, here are some other thoughts if it's not.

First, when you say you can access it from your browser, do you mean as http://yourserver/yourcfc.cfc?method=methodname? Or something else? And since you show your ajax library adding returnformat=json, are you adding that on the URL as well to test?

Second, when you say you're using no application.cfc or cfm, do you realize it's not just whether there's one in that directory, but any in the parent, grandparent, and so on? You could be influenced by one of those. The easiest way to avoid it (for testing purposes) is to drop a blank one into the directory of the page you're calling.

Third, if you look in the application.log file (in [cf]\logs, or via the CF Admin), does it show an error happening? The Ajax client will typically hide that. Indeed, you mention getting a 404. Are you sure that's the CFC that's not being found? What's reporting that?

And is the CFC in the same directory as the CF page that served up this HTML/javascript? Since you only name the file, it would seem it would be looking there. Were you testing that with your sample URL in the browser?

Comment: I'm not on my work vlan at the moment so I can't test with the returnformat=json although that is specified in the cfc as well. I did use the url as you showed there with the method and arguments passed along the query string. I do not believe that there is an application.cfc anywhere in my heirarchy but will test that in the AM as well. I am getting the error from the error function of my Ajax call. I will also check the logs for the information you requested. I appreciate all the suggestions, and will post again once I've had the oppurtunity to follow up on them.

Comment: Alright here is my list of results from your suggestions, and again thank you:

-Calling in a browser by url works, even with returnFormat=json in the URL. 

-Adding a blank application.cfc did not resolve this.

-The cfc is in the same directory as the page serving this script. and yes I was.

-I am getting access to the logs I think that may be the right track as firebug reports an internal server error from IIS (http 500).

Comment: Problem is with the data being passed to my CFC. Thanks for all the help, I should be able to get this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

make sure the CFC method is marked as access="remote".

If you do http://servername/path/to/cfc/nameofcfc.cfc?method=methodName&arg1=arg1value (replacing values with your values) does it work?  Take the "ajax" out of it